# mysqli multiple insert not submitting all lines from array

Tags: php, mysqli, bulkinsert

I have a big issue with my code I suspect.
It only adds the first of `$species`, `$weight` and `$length`. but if there is more than one value in the **$_Post**. 
It should submit them as well from my form. I am having trouble seeing where I have gone wrong. 
I hope somebody, can point me in the right direction?

```
<?php

require 'config.php';

$teamid = $_POST['teamid'];
$species = $_POST['species']; // Can be multiple values depending on how many lines added from form
$weight = $_POST['weight']; // Can be multiple values depending on how many lines added from form
$length = $_POST['length']; // Can be multiple values depending on how many lines added from form

// count($species),($weight),($length) - Should always be the same length

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO indvejninger ( teamid, artid, vaegt, laengde) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){

            foreach ($species as $key => $value) {

            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $_POST['teamid'], $param_species, $param_weight, $param_length);

            $param_species = $species[$key];
            $param_weight = $weight[$key];
            $param_length = $length[$key];

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: index.php?limit=");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }       

        // Close statement
        $stmt->close();

        }

    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, after first submit it changes url. So it does not finish the other submissions.

```
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if($stmt->execute()){
            // Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
            header("location: index.php?limit=");
            exit();
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
```

So instead, I need it to finish the other submissions, and then redirect to landing page.